# c:if condition not evaluating to true

Tags: if-statement, primefaces, datatable, xhtml

I have the following code in a `xhtml` where `app` is a variable in a [primefaces](http://primefaces.org/) `dataTable`:

```
${app.paas.id_paas == var.DESIGN_APP}

<c:if test="${app.paas.id_paas == var.DESIGN_APP}">
    <script>
        console.log("inside!");
    </script> 
</c:if>
```

Where the page prints `true` but the console does not print `inside!`.
Why isn't the `c:if` entering the condition?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the JSTL instead of facelets.
your

```
c:if
```

code is executed during **build time** while your primefaces variables are processed at **render time**.
See here for the full explanation :[JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)